# Using the same source of a manual to build a PDF-file and a website reference|wiki

Tags: pdf, website, wiki

Me and my colleagues are constantly facing one problem, which I don't see a solution for yet. I hope you can advice me a good one. Let's say, we have a manual or a text-book, which should be both printable, and viewed offline. As I understand, PDF-file is the best what we can have,  and PDF bookmarks is one of the things which we definitely must have. Additionally, we would like to put the information on a website, so users can google it, comment some pages, or even modify if is a wiki. Basically, we want all benefits of Web2.0 + making a nice PDF (or may be other format giving similar features). What would you use to meet these objectives?

Comment: Have you looked into the latex2html conversions? LaTeX usually makes the nicest publication quality documents. But if you want web-usage also maybe docbook would meet both requirements. The hg manual is an [Example](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) with [source](https://bitbucket.org/bos/hgbook).

Answer (score 2):

You need [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) - MediaWiki is the engine running Wikipedia

Example, see wikipedia, look up [Sailing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailing)

In the left menu there is a menu item that says Print/Export, click that and Create a Book, this works with many (if not all) mediawiki articles.

Good Luck!

Comment: This looks really great! However, I would rather prefer to compile PDF/HTML from sources, e.g. LaTeX.